# `js` and `jb` instructions in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I am having a hard time understanding what exactly `js` and `jb` instruction do. I understand that `jb` is jump if below. But, what would be the difference between `jb` and `jle`. And similarly, `js` seems to me that it is equivalent to `jb`, as it means jump if signed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `js` tests the Sign flag, and `jb` tests the Carry flag. `jle` is more complex and your assembler / processor text books are the place to begin. One uses a different set of flag tests for signed and unsigned arithmetic, as the processor does not (usually) distinguish the two.

Comment: The instruction set reference clearly shows which flags each test. `js` examines the sign flag so you can check for negative numbers. `jb` is for unsigned comparison as it uses the carry flag.  `jl` is for signed comparison which handles overflow as well. In the given code `js` just checks whether the MSB of `eax` is set or not (meaning it's negative if viewed as signed). The `jb` is just doing an unsigned less-than.

Comment: http://felixcloutier.com/x86/Jcc.html

Comment: The conditional jumps check the flags (`eflag` register), they are not aware of which instruction did produce the flag. I.e. `stc` `jb somewhere` will take the branch to `somewhere` always, because `stc` is "set carry flag" - yet it doesn't have anything to do with human concept of "below" term (and reasonable programmer would rather write the `jc` alias there to not confuse reader by "below", but make it clear that he is interested into "carry" status).

Answer (score 10):

There exists a handy table that does explain very well which `Jcc` instruction to use:

**Jump conditions and flags:**

```
Mnemonic        Condition tested  Description  
jo              OF = 1            overflow 
jno             OF = 0            not overflow 
jc, jb, jnae    CF = 1            carry / below / not above nor equal
jnc, jae, jnb   CF = 0            not carry / above or equal / not below
je, jz          ZF = 1            equal / zero
jne, jnz        ZF = 0            not equal / not zero
jbe, jna        CF or ZF = 1      below or equal / not above
ja, jnbe        CF or ZF = 0      above / not below or equal
js              SF = 1            sign 
jns             SF = 0            not sign 
jp, jpe         PF = 1            parity / parity even 
jnp, jpo        PF = 0            not parity / parity odd 
jl, jnge        SF xor OF = 1     less / not greater nor equal
jge, jnl        SF xor OF = 0     greater or equal / not less
jle, jng    (SF xor OF) or ZF = 1 less or equal / not greater
jg, jnle    (SF xor OF) or ZF = 0 greater / not less nor equal
```

Answer (score 5):

`jb` (and `ja`) branch based on the *unsigned* result of the flags, as opposed to the *signed* branch condition for `jg`, `jge`, `jl`, and `jle`.

In an unsigned comparison, the MSB is included as part of the number itself and not an indication of its sign.  For example:

```
 ; Intel                          ; ; AT&T
 mov eax, 08000000h               ; mov $0x8000000, %eax
 mov ecx, 00000001h               ; mov $0x0000001, %ecx
 cmp eax, ecx                     ; cmp %ecx, %eax
 jl mybranch ; branch taken       ; jl mybranch ; branch taken
```

Whereas:

```
 mov eax, 08000000h               ; mov $0x8000000, %eax
 mov ecx, 00000001h               ; mov $0x0000001, %ecx
 cmp eax, ecx                     ; cmp %ecx, %eax
 jb mybranch ; branch not taken   ; jb mybranch ; branch not taken
```

`js` will branch based solely on the state of the sign flag in the `(R|E)FLAGS` register

Comment: The OP is using GAS, which only supports `0x...` syntax for hex, not DOS-style `0...h`.  (And they have it in AT&T syntax mode, not `.intel_syntax noprefix`).

Comment: @PeterCordes I was going to edit my post but it looks like some one beat me to it :)